# Stress test a single node of the cluster

Tags: cassandra, datastax, nosql

I am new to cassandra and I have created a 4 node cassandra cluster. To see the improvements gained for adding nodes I wanted to stress sub-groups of nodes my cluster. I want to something like, having two of the nodes as the cluster while the other two free nodes as the inserting clients, how should I go to do this?

I have tried with the the -pop seq=1..1000000 to select the 1st node but I was monitoring the usages and I could notice that unused non-inserting nodes were being used too. Maybe I am using this option wrong? I found the datastax article a bit confusing to me regarding the use of this option.

I could potentially decommission the nodes I don't want/ want to use as insert clients, but I assume there must be a simpler way.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So I think you are using Cassandra Stress in a wrong way.
If you wish to test improvement in performance

Reduce your cluster to 1 node.
Run Cassandra-Stress(or YCSB) from a Server which is not in the Cluster
Note down the results for single node.

Add a node to your cluster(so now you should have a 2 node cluster)
Run Cassandra-Stress(or YCSB) from a Server which is not in the Cluster.
Note down the results for 2 node cluster.
Make sure you add the `-hosts CassandraNode1IP,CassandraNode2IP`
when you run the benchmarking tool.

Add 2 more nodes to your cluster(so now you should have a 4 node cluster)
Run Cassandra-Stress(or YCSB) from a Server which is not in the Cluster.
Note down the results for 4 node cluster.
Make sure you add the

`-hosts CassandraNode1IP,CassandraNode2IP,CassandraNode3IP,CassandraNode4IP`

when you run the benchmarking tool.

Comment: What if I want multiple clients inserting into a cluster, do I need to launch the stress test from each one individually? Or is there as single command I can use in which I can select the ips of the client machine I want inserting

Comment: You can launch the stress test from each one individually.

Comment: Ok, a single machine is not enough to saturate the cluster